# Find your way out of the temple

Tags: logical-deduction

You and 8 other students are trapped inside a temple and the temple will collapse in an hour.There are four ways, out of which only way one leads out and the other three have dead ends. Also one of the ways is cursed and it curses any two people on that path. Cursed students will lie occasionally(i.e. lie randomly). Assuming that all paths are equally long and you reach the dead end in 20 minutes. Devise a strategy to safely get out of the temple.

**Edit:**

You are cursed at the end of path. Nobody can tell if they(or someone else) are cursed or not. **Also you cannot be cursed.**

Comment: occasionally lie?

Comment: If I'm cursed, will I know it?

Comment: when the curse hapoens?

Comment: @Oray, I edited the question.

Comment: @Kepotx, edited.

Comment: what is the meaning of lie in your question? saying wrong or?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Is the capital I (second letter in Find) in the title capitalised on purpose?

Comment: @Oray, it means that the cursed students will lie randomly. Like you ask two cursed students if 2+2=4, they may say yes or no while others will say yes.

Comment: This seems identical to [this riddle](https://youtu.be/nSbvlktToSY). Unless you happened to come up with the exact same riddle independently, please attribute the source in your question.

Comment: @Riley, the original author is unknown.

Comment: Even if the original author is unknown, you should still mention in the question where you heard it from.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [The Expedition Into The Ancient Cave](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/28800)

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Just for clarity and completeness: For content you did not create yourself, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)**. At minimum you need to let us know where you got it from. Posts which use someone else's content without disclosing where it came from are generally deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can't be cursed

> I can go alone, leaving 8 students for 3 path
>  
>  Split the students in two groups of 3 and one group of two
>  
>  As only **two** students can be cursed, the group of three will either all say the same, or say different things. If they say different things, we know they are cursed. 
>  The only problem is the group of two : either they argue, and you know they are cursed, or they agree. but they can both lie.
>  But as we know the result of other three path, it doesn't matter: if I or a group of three claim to know the exit, we know the group of two lie